# what's the difference between managed bean and spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, controller, javabeans

I am developing spring-hibernate-jsf application but i dont understand the difference between a managedbean and a spring controller. I think managedbeans work like controllers. Is there any advantage of using controller or managedbean?

Comment: The difference is that they are different. Not a real question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18388289 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/18744910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed Beans provides services and are used as model for UI components. Controllers are request/response components like Servlets.

JSF is a component based web framework & Spring is a DI framework. JSF & Spring manages their own beans, so to reference ManagedBeans and inject in them you need to mark JSF ManagedBeans as Spring Controllers using @Controller annotation.

If you are thinking of replacing one with other, then no you have to use both of them if you want to use both Spring & JSF together.

Comment: i just changed my managedbeans to controller(i just add @controller annotiation and delete @managedbean) and it gives "exampleController resolved to null...".

Comment: You need to keep both `@ManagedBean` and `@Controller` annotations, for JSF and Spring respectively.

Comment: I would use managed bean only as *controller* for the UI interface and use Spring for DI and classes injection. Still, if you would work in a Java EE environment, it would be better to use EJB instead of Spring (and maybe JPA implemented by Hibernate).