# JSF change relative path of resources of login via Spring security

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc, spring-security, rendering

Our application is a Jee application includes the following technologies:

- Spring
- Spring Security
- JSF 2.2
- Spring Webflow
- Spring MVC

Before login , Resources (images,css,js,..) have been loaded successfully :

```
<link href="/titi/javax.faces.resource/layout/layout.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/titi/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After Login ,  relative paths rendering was changed :

1. There is a new folder in the path which is `/apps/` .
2. There is no `.xhtml` as extension .

__

```
 <link href="/titi/apps/javax.faces.resource/layout/layout.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="/titi/apps/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

What is the configuration should be added for Spring Security to  not  interfere in resources path ?

## Why `/apps/` ?

I search on my code to understand why `apps` , i note that `apps` token from `web.xml` :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/apps/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are taking the wrong approach and have the wrong assumptions. JSF and Spring MVC don't mix. See [Using JSF as view technology of Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744910/using-jsf-as-view-technology-of-spring-mvc)