# Does it make sense to combine Spring with JSF?

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

In some projects, I often used Spring + Spring MVC. Personally, I prefer using pure Java EE 7, in particular CDI + JSF.

I'm wondering if it is a good choice to use Spring as the DI container and JSF as the presentation layer.

Comment: You can use JSF on top of Spring. Since both Spring MVC and JSF are MVC frameworks. they cannot be used together (you can however, use Facelets with Spring MVC but it is a different story). The rest is only opinion based which I personally always choose to remain silent about. Choose in which you are interested most.

Comment: Ah... of course. Facelets is the view technology, not JSF itself. My mistake. I updated the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18379228/1391249, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18745266/1391249

Comment: So you can technically do the same things using either CDI or Spring? It's more or less just the object wiring annotations that are different?

Comment: It is clearly mentioned in the duplicate link.