# JSF, spring security integration, how to configure the dataSource jdbc

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

My question is: would it make sens to use a [tutorial like this (point 5)](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-and-resource-bundles-example/) considering I'm using the JSF framework ?
I know spring and jsf shouldn't be mixed up but I don't know where to draw the line really.

In the spring security documentation they inject the datasource for the JDBC authentication like this:

```
@Autowired private DataSource dataSource; // This, I don't know what to do

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .withDefaultSchema()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}
```

I'm using JSF and my datasource is specified nowhere and I'm kinda relunctant to use spring related techniques because of this : [Using JSF as view technology of Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744910/using-jsf-as-view-technology-of-spring-mvc)

Comment: Do you have a provider for the `DataSource`? Do you know how Spring works by itself?

Comment: Wherw is this jsf related? I only see spring/java code in the example

Comment: @Luiggi no, not really, I guess I've to declare my datasource in an application-contyext?

Comment: Yes, you must declare the datasource bean in a Spring XML config file or use a `@Configuration` class that provides a datasource through `@Bean`. I recommend you to review Spring first, then start using other frameworks on top of it like Spring Security.

Comment: But I'm using JSF which I think means I'll only use spring security for the security. The rest will be handled by jsf.

Comment: You do not use any other spring things? Any specific reason to use it then and not some other framework (not that spring-security is bad)

Comment: None, I just heard about it. The vanilla java ee security system is bad though. But since I started with it (spring security) I should keep on. Furthermore I read that I didn't especially need to know the spring framework to get going. I just need to figure out how to configure this datasource thing then I can keep on coding my web app and maybe come back on the security in the future. But at the moment I would like to build my web app though. I just learned JSF framework to do so.

Comment: @Kukeltje This post from BalusC seems to say (last paragraph) that jsf is relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744910/using-jsf-as-view-technology-of-spring-mvc

Comment: Waht do you mean by this last comment? I fail to see the relation with your question (after a quick look)

Comment: Btw I meant that if you do no use any spring stuff, why did you go for spring security and not shiro or (imo) even better, with picketlink

Comment: This blog post may be helpful for you http://mprabhat.com/2012/09/23/integrating-spring-security-3-1-and-jsf-2-0/

Comment: kukelje oh please if there is another better alternative I'm gonna take it. So I'll be going with picketlink. People advised me to use spring security.