# How to get <f:attribute> value inside <p:ajax listener> method?

Tags: jsf, attributes, components

I have a checkbox component with a `<f:attribute>` and a `<p:ajax listener>`.

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox ...>
  <p:ajax listener="#{locationHandler.setChangedSOI}" />
  <f:attribute name="Dummy" value="test" />
  ...
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

I tried to get the `<f:attribute>` value of `test` inside the listener method as below:

```
public void setChangedSOI() throws Exception {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String r1 = map.get("Dummy");
    System.out.println(r1);
}
```

However, it printed `null`. How can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Component attributes are not passed as HTTP request parameters. Component attributes are set as .. uh, component attributes. I.e. they are stored in `UIComponent#getAttributes()`. You can grab them through that map.

Now the right question is obviously how to get the desired `UIComponent` inside the ajax listener method. There are 2 ways for this:

1. Specify the [`AjaxBehaviorEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/AjaxBehaviorEvent.html) argument. It offers a [`getComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/FacesEvent.html#getComponent()) method for the very purpose.

   ```
   public void setChangedSOI(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
       UIComponent component = event.getComponent();
       String dummy = component.getAttributes().get("Dummy");
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Use the [`UIComponent#getCurrentComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) helper method.

   ```
   public void setChangedSOI() {
       UIComponent component = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
       String dummy = component.getAttributes().get("Dummy");
       // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi BalusC,  on using your first option i get the following error, Jun 25, 2015 1:26:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet threw exception
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/certificates/locationList.xhtml @162,118 listener="#{locationHandler.setChangedSOI}": Method not found: com.csc.exceed.certificate.web.LocationHandler@1ecd6fb.setChangedSOI()
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:109)

Comment: Is there something that we can't call a method with AjaxBehaviourEvent as parameter using primefaces?

Comment: What the heck is a Spring MVC dispatcher servlet doing in a JSF request? Do you understand/know what you're doing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744910/using-jsf-as-view-technology-of-spring-mvc/

Comment: I have done such a thing previously also using <f:ajax> in place of <p:ajax> . It's working there.                                       <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="locationSelection" disabled="#{certInfo.selectableLocation}"
           value="#{certInfo.selectedLocation}" class="locSelection">
           <f:ajax execute="@this"
            listener="#{locationHandler.selectAllSOIs}"
            render="InsurenceList InsurenceListNEW" />
           <f:attribute name="modifiedLoc" value="#{certInfo}" />
          </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>