# Spring Web Flow - JSF - PrimeFaces Integration : UrlBasedViewResolver adds incorrect URL on JSF action

Tags: spring-mvc, facelets, spring-webflow-2, spring-faces

**UrlBasedViewResolver prefix is appended to the URL multiple times so that the resouces are not found.**

Spring Version: 4.2.0.RELEASE   Spring Web Flow Version:
   2.4.2.RELEASE   PrimeFaces: 5.2 JSF (jsf-api and jsf-impl): 2.2.12

```
<servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>



<context-param> 
            <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value> 
        </context-param>


 <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
            <param-value>1</param-value>
        </context-param>




<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>





<servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>



 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
         <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
         <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>




    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param> 



    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>




    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
             <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
            <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        </filter-mapping> 





     <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>





<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
    public class WebConfig{

    @Autowired
    private SpringWebFlowConfig webFlowConfig;


    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping() {
        FlowHandlerMapping mapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setOrder(1);
        mapping.setFlowRegistry(this.webFlowConfig.flowRegistry());
        mapping.setDefaultHandler(new UrlFilenameViewController());
        return mapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter() {
        JsfFlowHandlerAdapter adapter = new JsfFlowHandlerAdapter();
        adapter.setFlowExecutor(this.webFlowConfig.flowExecutor());
        adapter.setSaveOutputToFlashScopeOnRedirect(true);
        return adapter;
    }


    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver faceletsViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JsfView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsfaces/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
        return resolver;
    }



    @Bean
    public SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter simpleControllerHandlerAdapter() {
        return new SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter();
    }


}
```

**SpringWebFlowConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class SpringWebFlowConfig extends AbstractFacesFlowConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
        return getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry())
                .addFlowExecutionListener(new FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener())
                .addFlowExecutionListener(new SecurityFlowExecutionListener())
                //.addFlowExecutionListener(persistenceListener())
                .build();
    }


   @Bean
    public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
        return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder(flowBuilderServices())
                .setBasePath("/WEB-INF/flows")
                .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml")
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
        return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder().setDevelopmentMode(true).build();
    }

}
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

       <application>
        <message-bundle>/messages/JsfMessageResources</message-bundle>
       </application> 


    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">



    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.efacec.oms.powr.controller" />  

    <mvc:resources mapping="/app/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
</beans>



**Folder Structure**

WEB-INF
 -- flows -->account-flow.xml    test-flow.xml welcome-flow.xml
 -- jsfaces  --> accountHome.xml   welcome.xhtml   testFlow.xml
 -- templates  --> general.xhtml

**welcome-flow.xml**
```

**welcome-flow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <var name="user" class="com.domain.UserEntity"/>


    <view-state id="welcome"  view="welcome.xhtml" model="user">
        <transition on="signOn" to="authentication">
        </transition> 
    </view-state>


    <action-state id="authentication"> 
        <evaluate expression="userService.authenticate(user)" />
        <transition on="success" to="finish" />
        <transition on="failure" to="welcome" />
    </action-state>


    <end-state id="finish" view="externalRedirect:account" /> 

</flow>
```

**account-flow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">



    <var name="uiUtils" class="com.jsf.utils.UIUtils"/>


    <view-state id="account" view="accountHome.xhtml">
    </view-state>

</flow>
```

**JSF Event:**  inside welcome.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton id="submitButton" action="signOn"
                    value="Sign In" />
```

On clicking the button

It adds resolver prefix multiple times("/WEB-INF/jsfaces/") in the URL so that the resources are not found

Error encountered:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.faces.FacesException: **/WEB-INF/jsfaces/WEB-INF/jsfaces/**welcome.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    com.efacec.oms.powr.filter.TokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(TokenAuthenticationFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
```

Comment: I see that you're using JSF 2.2 instead of JSF 2.0/2.1. I can imagine why you'd like to use Spring WebFlow on JSF 2.0/2.1, but it's weird to see it on JSF 2.2 because since that version JSF comes with builtin Flow  feature. Are you aware of this? Java EE 7 tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-configure003.htm By the way,  the attempt to mix Spring MVC with PrimeFaces is scary. Food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18744910

Comment: The application needs to provide rest services(spring),backend is fully spring configured  and I would  like to use JSF at front end.