# Remove Spring WebFlow "execution" request parameter from JSF forms

Tags: spring, jsf-2, spring-webflow, http-request-parameters

I have a Spring 4.1.7 + Spring WebFlow 2.4.1 + JSF 2.0 project. I would like to get rid of the request parameter that is added by Spring WebFlow, i.e. `execution=e15s1`. I want to get rid of this during transition of the view state as well.

```
<webflow:flow-execution-attributes>
    <!-- without execution param -->
    <webflow:always-redirect-on-pause value="false"/>
</webflow:flow-execution-attributes>
```

I have put the above configuration in flow executor. It helps for start state, but when submitting a JSF form like below,

```
<h:form id="loginForm"> 
  <h:commandButton  value="Login" class="button button-sp" action="Hotelier"/>
</h:form>
```

the Spring WebFlow request parameter shows up in URL again like so `?execution=e12s1`.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Sorry, but Spring webfow is designed to work on Spring MVC. Trying to configure it for JSF would be a headache for you, as JSF has its own flow. Totally incompatible frameworks, IMHO. What you can do is replace JSF by Spring MVC or just remove the Spring webflow from your project, keeping JSF + Spring core.

Comment: Faces flow is only available since JSF 2.2, indeed making Spring WebFlow superfluous. On a second thought after cleaning up your question, what exactly do you need Spring WebFlow for if you  apparently don't want the flow scope at all?

Comment: What about Spring MVC and JSF?

Comment: Food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18744910

Comment: put this question on the SWF Jira page and see what they say: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWF

Comment: the question is not clear. what is hapening in your flow.xml on the Hotelier action? and what do you expect to happen?