# primefaces datatable columnfooter cannot show data

Tags: spring-mvc, primefaces, datatable, spring-webflow

I am using primefaces with spring webflow and mvc. In xhtml, I have one p:datatable inside ui:repeater. With columnGroup footer type, all value cannot show in footer but the content can show. 
I have tried to set the footer column's background color and also does not work.
I have tried to set the value from controller function and also does not work and set the debugging point in controller but it does not go to.
I have tried to set the value from the datatable value object vo class and also does not work even with set debugging point and it does not go to.

Do you know where is the problem?? But I does not use column footer and separate it from datatable and make new another panelGrid within ui:repeater. It can show.

```
<p:columnGroup type="footer"> 
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column footerText="#{esLabel['lbl.esstv1s6.lblTotal']}"><p:outputLabel value="#{esLabel['lbl.esstv1s6.lblTotal']}"  id="lblTitle1s6a16"/></p:column>
                            <p:column style="#{servingSchool.schllevltypecode eq '1' ? 'background-color:silver' : ''}"><p:outputLabel  value="#{servingSchool.totalOrgPrimary}"/></p:column>
                            <p:column><p:outputLabel value="#{servingSchool.totalOrgJs}"/></p:column>
                            <p:column><p:outputLabel value="#{servingSchool.totalOrgNss}"/></p:column>
                            <p:column><p:outputLabel value="#{servingSchool.totalOrgOfTotal}"/></p:column>
                            <p:column footerText="#{esLabel['lbl.esstv1s6.lblTotal']}"><p:outputLabel value="#{esLabel['lbl.esstv1s6.lblTotal']}"  id="lblTitle1s6a17"/></p:column>
                            <p:column style="#{servingSchool.schllevltypecode eq '1' ? 'background-color:silver' : ''}"><p:outputLabel  value="#{servingSchool.getTotalUpdPrimary()}"/></p:column>
                            <p:column><p:outputLabel value="#{servingSchool.getTotalUpdJs()}"/></p:column>
                            <p:column><p:outputLabel value="#{teacherVerificationController.getTotal('TotalUpdNss',servingSchool)}"/></p:column>
                            <p:column><p:outputLabel value="#{servingSchool.getTotalUpdOfTotal()}"/></p:column>
                        </p:row>
                        </p:columnGroup>
```

Comment: have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744910/using-jsf-as-view-technology-of-spring-mvc?