# Combining a spring REST Service with a JSF Page

Tags: spring, maven

ive tried the [spring REST tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) and i also got a simple JSF application (running on glassfish), both projects are maven based and i would like to "combine" them.
Meaning, putting the REST project jar into the JSF project.
Does that make sense?

The JSF page should send a request to the microservice REST project when it starts and display the result.

the REST project uses spring-boot and therefore tomcat.
this [pom.xml](https://github.com/edsonjnior/springboot-glassfish4/blob/master/pom.xml) is supposed to use glassfish instead of tomcat, at least thats what the author tells on a [spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications).

Theres a part in it:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

That says to "exclude" tomcat - which is fine, but how does maven or spring know to use glassfish instead?

Is there maybe a better way to combine these two projects?
I would like to keep the projects seperate because of the dependencys in the pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Answer #1 in this question solves the confusion:
[Using JSF as view technology of Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744910/using-jsf-as-view-technology-of-spring-mvc)

spring mvc and jsf are rivals.