# Error creating bean with name 'managedBeanClass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'person':

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new comer for the spring-mvc. I tried to find good tutorial for develop test project using spring-mvc, hibernate, mysql and jsf. Finally I created sample project.

[image: Here] is capture of my project

**My first question is,**

> Is this spring-mvc structure

But unfortunately it's show above error.

**applicationContext.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config />

        <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <beans:property name="url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vehicles" />
            <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
            <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
        </beans:bean> 

        <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
        <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
                <beans:list>
                    <beans:value>com.journaldev.springhibernate.model.Person</beans:value>
                </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
                <beans:props>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                    </beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                </beans:props>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>



        <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev" />

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

        <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
        </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

**web.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

**Person class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person {
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@Column(name="country")
private String country;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "id="+id+", name="+name+", country="+country;
}
}
```

**PersonDAOImpl class**

```
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO{

private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class);

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
    this.sessionFactory = sf;
}

@Override
public void addPerson(Person p) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.persist(p);
    logger.info("Person saved successfully, Person Details="+p);
}

}
```

**PersonServiceImpl class**

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

@Autowired
private PersonDAO personDAO;

@Override
@Transactional
public void addPerson(Person p) {
    personDAO.addPerson(p);
}
}
```

**ManagedBeanClass class**

```
@ManagedBean("managedBeanClass")
@ViewScoped
public class ManagedBeanClass implements Serializable{

@Autowired
private Person person;

@Autowired
private PersonService personServiceImpl;

public void addPersion(){
    personServiceImpl.addPerson(person);

}

public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}

public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
}

}
```

**Error is,**

```html
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'managedBeanClass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'person': No qualifying bean of type [com.journaldev.springhibernate.model.Person] found for dependency [com.journaldev.springhibernate.model.Person]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.journaldev.springhibernate.model.Person] found for dependency [com.journaldev.springhibernate.model.Person]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Aug 28, 2017 5:04:46 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'managedBeanClass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'person': No qualifying bean of type [com.journaldev.springhibernate.model.Person] found for dependency [com.journaldev.springhibernate.model.Person]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.journaldev.springhibernate.model.Person] found for dependency [com.journaldev.springhibernate.model.Person]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.journaldev.springhibernate.model.Person] found for dependency [com.journaldev.springhibernate.model.Person]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 24 more
```

Please give me a answer. I tried this since long time. I can build project using spring. But I need to build with `spring-mvc` with  **@Autowired** annotation.

Comment: Spring MVC and jsf are sort of competing technologies... Do you actually mix them?

Comment: @kukeltje thank you. I don't know what are you saying me. I don't know more things about this. Am I wrong with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744910/using-jsf-as-view-technology-of-spring-mvc

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje Ill read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ManagedBeanClass class you try to autowire a entity. Entitys are not autowire candidates.

Change the class to

```
@Autowired
private Person person;

       to 

private Person person = new Person();
```

Yes you can use `@Autowire` to let spring create a prototype scoped instance of the entity. But it is dirty because a entity is neither a dependency nor a context for ManagedBeanClass, the entity is the model of ManagedBeanClass. A model is not a dependency because the ManagedBeanClass MUST be able to create its model by itself, not let spring handle it.

Anyway, you like to have this dirty solution.

Assuming the entity is in the package of `com.journaldev`, add this to the entity:

```
@Bean                                                         <-new
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)               <-new 

@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person {
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Its ok so how can I use @Autowired anotation with spring.

Comment: I need to use @Autowired annotation in staid of private Person person = new Person();

Comment: @Dev4World You realy should make the field `final` and the value `null`.